# How to re-render children of a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

On the application page, an object that has many child components. When I change the value of the select, I get (using the vuex) a new object (the new value is stored in the state). How can I re-render this object?
Parent component:

```
    <edit-record-form
      :key="reRenderKey"
      ref="EditRecordForm"
      class="overflow-y-auto"
      v-on="$listeners"
      @toggle="toggleVersion($event)"
    />

    toggleVersion (ver) {
       this.reRenderKey += ver
    },
```

Select in child component:

```
 <v-select
  label="History. Version #"
  :items="listVersions"
  @input="getSelectedVersion"
/>

async getSelectedVersion (value) {
  if ('_id' in this.entity) {
    await this.getHistory({
      id: this.entity._id.$oid,
      version: value,
    })
  }
  this.$emit('toggle', 1)
},
```

I used the key to recreate the component( via this [article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/key-changing-technique/)), but only its destruction works.